# Discontinuity in multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

How to prove that f is discontinuous at origin using epsilon delta method?

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}&\text{$x\neq y$}\\ 0&\text{}x=y\end{cases}$$

I could prove discontinuity by putting $y=x-mx^3$. But I am unable to prove using the above method. I need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta$ be a real number greater than $0$. Let $x,h\in(0,+\infty)$. Then$$f(x+h,x)=h^2+3hx+3x^2+\frac{2x^3}h>\frac{2x^3}h.$$So$$f\bigl(\sqrt[4]h+h,\sqrt[4]h\bigr)>\frac{2\sqrt[4]h^3}h=\frac2{\sqrt[4]h}\text,$$which will be greater than or equal to $1$ when $0<h\leqslant16$. So, pick $h$ such that the distance from $(\sqrt[4]h+h,\sqrt[4]h)$ to $(0,0)$ is smaller than $\delta$, that is, such that $(\sqrt[4]h+h)^2+\sqrt h<\delta^2$, and then $|f(\sqrt[4]h+h,\sqrt[4]h)|\geqslant1$.

Note that $(\sqrt[4]h+h)^2+\sqrt h=3\sqrt h+2\sqrt[4]hh+h^2<6\sqrt h$ if $0<h<1$. So, in order to have $(\sqrt[4]h+h)^2+\sqrt h<\delta^2$, all you need is that $6\sqrt h<\delta^2$ (and $h<1$, of course).

Comment: How did you take the function f(x,y) to be f(x+h,x)?

Comment: @user464068 It's so that the denominator is small and therefore fso that the value of the function is away from $0$.

Comment: Okay. How did f(x+h,x) become f(h+h^4,h)?

Comment: @user464068 It didn't. I *chose* $x=h^4$.

Comment: Then it should've been f(h+h^4, h^4), right?

Comment: @user464068 Right. I shall edit my answer. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @user464068 Done (I hope!).

Comment: @user464068 I don't see why. But I shall be off the Internet from some time starting now.

Comment: Yeah, it looks great. Thank you so much for your time. Have a great day!